# Docker in debugging mode

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have flume, hdfs container running in boot2docker. I have java code under my `/c/users/` directory which is automatically mounted by boot2docker[According to [docs](https://www.docker.com/)].

I copied required jars into running container instead mounting the volume using `-v` flag. Now i want to debug my code inside the running container.

How do i achieve this? Do i need to mount this and then run the container with debug mode? how do  i do this? If any steps or example, then it would be really helpful

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use `docker exec -ti container /bin/bash` to open a terminal in your container, check the dock https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec

Comment: After running like this, then i copied code. I want to know how to debu step by step like we do IDE

Comment: define a DISPLAY and install your IDE in your container, by debugging, I understood launching some commands in a terminal

Comment: No man. I am pretty sure there is a way to link eclipse with docker by running here we can debug step by step. If i am wrong, please correct me

Comment: Yes you have 31 conatiners with eclipse at https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=eclipse&searchfield= but you are back to what I said, install Eclipse in your container, or get a container with Eclipse and install your stuff